# Will this trigger significantly degrade performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mariadb, trigger, query-performance

I have this trigger to (do my best) to prevent brute forcing logins. It has two seperate functions:

1. If a failed login has been attempted more than 4 times (so read that exactly 5 times) from the same IP address within the last three minutes, that IP_address is added to the blacklisted_ips table. The IP address then has a "cool down" time period specified by a column in the table.
2. If a failed login has been attempted more than 3 times (so read that exactly 4 times) from the same username within the last two minutes (so IP address agnostic), then the username is added to the blacklisted_usernames table. The username then has a "cool down" time period specified by a column in the table.

My question is, looking at this trigger, it looks performance inefficient to me. Am I correct in thinking that, or is the performance effect negligible?

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_brute_force 
AFTER INSERT ON login_att 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SELECT ip_add, was_success INTO @ip, @result 
    FROM login_att 
    ORDER BY login_att_id DESC LIMIT 1;

    SELECT ip_add INTO @check_ip 
    FROM login_att 
    WHERE login_att_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) 
      AND ip_add = @ip 
    HAVING COUNT(ip_add) > 4;

    IF @check_ip IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 
        IF @result = 0
        THEN
            INSERT INTO blacklisted_ips (ip_add) VALUES (@ip); 
        END IF;
    END IF;

    SELECT username_att into @username_att 
    FROM login_att 
    WHERE login_att_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
      AND was_success=0 HAVING COUNT(username_att) > 3;

    IF @username_att IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        INSERT INTO blacklisted_users (username) VALUES (@username_att);
    END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to evaluate performance is by measuring it- you are the only person that can evaluate that on the real application, or, much better, on a staging environment with a copy of the traffic or an emulation of such.

Hardware, other code running, throughput, how slow are those new queries, amount of data you have, etc. will tell you what you want to know- to the point that the same code can make it or break it under different circumstances.

Having said that, if you just want a high level opinion of the idea will work, without knowing much about your system- I would personally would do this kind of analysis asynchronously based on external logs (or your login_att table), as normally you don't want to punish your normal users if the occurrences are not frequent enough. Also triggers are not my favorite way to handle application logic. However, if you cannot modify the source code, it doesn't add much to the total latency, and you test it and it seem acceptable, go on- but please test it doesn't break your application when there are thousands of parallel attempts per second due to the extra writes.

Comment: So I'm still in the development phase...so you would suggest just throwing a bunch of requests at it and seeing how it does?

Comment: yes- but gather good metrics- both before and after you apply it- that will be the most important factor to say how impacting it is. Maybe your database time is 1% of the total request on your "java enterprisy app". Maybe you have a light go application that spends most of the time running the trigger- only you can tell. But gather metrics (profile) all requests unders tress, and how much each applications step/function is responsible for.

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter.

A valid login is a tiny percentage of the total work a user does with the system, correct?  So, if that 'tiny' percentage grows, it is still a 'small' impact.

Meanwhile, who cares what happens with the hacker.

As for the overhead, it will be minor.

Answer (score 2):

I believe @RickJames makes a good point, but if you did want to optimize the trigger a bit anyway, there are a couple of things to note:

1. MySQL triggers (as well as stored routines and events) are parsed every time they are executed, which means they can be slow, or at least slower than compiled code. (However, running all the code inside the database might be faster than running the control flow in the application and SQL in the database since it takes time to send data back and forth to the database.) While the execution plans from SQL statements (within the same session) in a trigger or stored routine are stored for later and re-used, `IF` statements are re-parsed in their entirety every time so are therefore best avoided, though of course you often need them. In your case I can't quite see a way to make the code work without `IF`s.
2. Your first `SELECT` is unnecessary. In an `AFTER INSERT` trigger you can access the values from the inserted row by using the prefix `NEW` for the column names, so: `NEW.ip_add`, `NEW.was_success` will give you the values you need here.
3. Instead of the nested `IF` statements (`IF @check_ip ... THEN IF @result = 0 THEN`), you could just do `IF @check_ip IS NOT NULL AND NEW.was_success = 0 THEN`.